# Descriptive statistics in Stata - Word frequencies

Tags: statistics, stata, frequency-analysis

I have a large data set containing as variables fileid, year and about 1000 words (each word is a separate variable). All line entries come from company reports indicating the year, an unique fileid and the respective absolute frequency for each word in that report. Now I want some descriptive statistics: Number of words not used at all, Mean of words, variance of words, top percentile of words. How can I program that in Stata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caveat: You are probably better off using a text processing package in R or another program. But since no one else has answered, I'll give it a Stata-only shot. There may be an ado file already built that is much better suited, but I'm not aware of one.

I'm assuming that

> each word is a separate variable

means that there is a variable `word_profit` that takes a value k from 0 to K where `word_profit[i]` is the number of times profit is written in the i-th report, `fileid[i]`.

Mean of words

`collapse (mean) word_*` will give you the average number of times the words are used. Adding a `by(year)` option will give you those means by year. To make this more manageable than a very wide one observation dataset, you'll want to run the following after the collapse:

```
gen temp = 1
reshape long word_, i(temp) j(str) string
rename word_ count
drop temp
```

Variance of words

`collapse (std) word_*` will give you the standard deviation. To get variances, just square the standard deviation.

Number of words not used at all

Without a bit more clarity, I don't have a good idea of what you want here. You could count zeros for each word with:

```
foreach var of varlist word_* {
  gen zero_`var' = (`var' == 0)
}
collapse (sum) zero_*
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help jfeigenbaum, realy appreciate. Can you explan what you are doing in the middle part of the mean of words? gen temp = 1
reshape long word_, i(temp) j(str) string
rename word_ count
drop temp    . And another question, after I have the mean and variance of words (by year), how can I filter out that ones that in relative terms showed the steepest tredn of increase/decrease( for example consider word_profit[2000]=10, word_profit[2001]=14, word_profit[2002]=15 -> CAGR = (15/10)^(2002-2000)-1=22.5% )

Comment: After the collapse, you'll have a dataset that has 1 observation and many variables (unless you collapse by year, then you'll have T observations and many variables). That's not the easiest data to do anything with. So the reshape makes the data long, where each observation is a different word along with its mean. But Stata (as far as I know) won't reshape without an i variable. So the temp variable serves that purpose.